# How to achive below multi dimentional array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
[USED] => Array
(
        [USER] => Array
        (
                [@attributes] => Array
                (
                        [NAME] => locuz
                        [HOST] => srpth1cn03.local
                        [IP] => 10.106.2.48
                        [USED_LICENSES] => 1
                        [LOGIN_TIME] => 2014-12-10 07:34
                        [CHECKOUT_TIME] => 2014-12-10 07:34
                )

        )

)
```

I want to change above array to below:

```
[USED] => Array
(
        [USER] => Array
        (
                [0] => Array
                (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                                [NAME] => rdtank
                                [HOST] => it30992
                                [IP] => 10.106.21.134
                                [DENIED_LICENSES] => 1
                                [LOGIN_TIME] => 2014-12-09 15:55
                                [DENIAL_TIME] => 2014-12-09 15:55
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Comment: And the question is ___ ?

Comment: Please specify your question. This is very unclear.

Comment: i want to convert above array to below array

Comment: [Edit] your question and read [ask] first

Comment: You didn't read [ask] at all. We won't code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `[]` before you save attributes as below.

```
foreach($all_attributes as $attributes){
  $sample_array['USED']['USER'][] = $attributes;
}
```

Comment: If there is more than one user result is fine. If only one user array formation is different. what i want is if single user or multiple, array formation should be same. I hope you understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

the code you wrote seems the result of 2 array dump.

so if you need to setup 2 variable in php that contains data you should use this code

```
<?php

    $used = array(
                'users' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'locuz',
                        'host' => 'srpth1cn03.local',
                        'ip' => '10.106.2.48',
                        'used_licenses' => 1,
                        'login_time' => '2014-12-10 07:34',
                        'checkout_time' => '2014-12-10 07:34'
                    )
                )
            );

    $denied = array(
                  'users' => array(
                      array(
                          'name' => 'rdtank',
                          'host' => 'it30992',
                          'ip' => '10.106.21.134',
                          'denied_licenses' => 1,
                          'login_time' => '2014-12-09 15:55',
                          'denial_time' => '2014-12-09 15:55'
                      )
                  )
              );
```

hope this helps.

Comment: That was not his question!